# Sharing intent of Reddit using android

Tags: android, reddit, android-sharing

Reddit sharing intent of share the screenshot image and share the URL in android.How to share the screenshot image and URL using Reddit app or web browser in android.

Comment: not clear what you want. Do you want to share image to Reddit?

Comment: yes,I want to share image to Reddit.